# Why are cells affected by time?

Tags: molecular-biology

We as individuals die when we get old. But why are cells affected by time? We are constantly providing energy to the cells through food, but the cells die after a certain time. Why does this happen?

Comment: _Anabolic processes vs Catabolic Processes_. When you search on Google. **what happens to cells overtime**, there are many articles you can read through answering your question.

Comment: @Kamal I rolled back your edit: please don't ask people to upvote you. Users will upvote if they think the question is useful.

Comment: Sir if I do not get any vote stack exchange will ban me.

Answer (score 2):

Individual cells don't live forever because they are damaged by their environment, for example by chemicals, radiation and mechanical wear and tear, or by other organisms (see [this review](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/77ec/de583e04f0d3a112eeabd458d5dbcc05d6b1.pdf)). In multicellular organisms, such "worn out" cells are typically dismantled by [programmed cell death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apoptosis) and new cells are generated to take their place.

The life span of animal cells varies widely depending on their location and function. For example, epithelial cells lining the skin and intestines are exposed to a harsh environment, and consequently [live only a couple of days](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1413255/). At the other extreme, neurons, which are safely lodged in the protected brain tissue, can live as long as the individual (or [even longer](http://www.pnas.org/content/110/11/4374.abstract)).

Note that the life span of a given cell is very different from replicative age, which refers to the number of divisions a cell *lineage* has undergone, measured from some progenitor cell. Most animal cells are allowed only a limited number of cell divisions (known as the [Hayflick limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayflick_limit)) and thus their lineage is "mortal", while that of microorganisms are not.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Not all cells do age and die, many symmetrically dividing unicellular cells are essentially immortal. In asymmetric species the occurs in many lines from the retention of old worn out [cellular machinery](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20537537). Triggered limited cell life only evolves later as organisms need to regulate multiple cells. It is likely a side effect of having cells specialize. However this origin is not conclusive, this is actually a vigorously debated subject in biology right now.

Comment: Can you cite some example of species where cells are considered immortal? I think life span is difficult to even *define* for unicellular organisms with symmetric cell division --- in one sense, such cells "die" in each cell division. For species with asymmetric division like budding yeast, cells generally age and die over time I think. See for example https://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v183/n4677/abs/1831751a0.html

Comment: "unicellular cells are essentially immortal" there's a search bar at top right corner (if you're on desktop version). Type "do bacteria die of old age?", hit enter and see what you get...

Comment: @another'Homosapien' Good catch I'll add a qualifier. symmetric dividing unicellular cells are essentially immortal. many asymmetric are not.

Comment: @Roland http://www.cell.com/current-biology/fulltext/S0960-9822(13)00973-1?_returnURL=http%3A%2F%2Flinkinghub.elsevier.com%2Fretrieve%2Fpii%2FS0960982213009731%3Fshowall%3Dtrue and https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20537537

Comment: @John, both of those studies actually claim that the cells studied have *asymmetric* cell division (defined by the old/new growth pole) and still do not age. That is very different from your statement "many symmetrically dividing unicellular cells are essentially immortal". My point was that the concept of cell age is meaningless if cell division is fully symmetric, as no cell is can be "older" than one division. (If symmetrically dividing cells would age and die, the species would die out ... )

Comment: @Roland I was just giving links for immortal lines, There is not a clear division between symmetric and asymmetric division it is a spectrum just like everything else in biology. Some cell lines are capable of both E coli is one of those. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4010982/.

Answer (score 0):

Regular cells are built to expire themselves when they detect too much damage (taking one for the team).

There are plenty of examples of cells that refuse to do so. Often, they're called cancer cells.

Answer (score -1):

I love questions like this! my reasoning is that while cells certainly have processes and mechanisms that exploit entropy, the bitter reality is that eventually something like our own cells will be subjected to entropy and will ultimately die and be disassociated. Every second a cell produces ATP to survive it is put under more and more oxidative stress and this is why cells age and ultimately die. It is also why less metabolically taxing lifeforms like a plant, can live for hundreds of years, as opposed to a mouse, which lives for like 3 years (an animal with a high metabolism)

my english is terrible so in short: energy is oxidation, oxidation reactions are entropy favored, this causes things to age. higher metabolism = more oxidation = shorter lifespan. Plants dont get up and run so they can live longer than animals which do

Comment: Sorry, but it sounds like you don't understand entropy. *All* reactions are driven by increasing entropy (that's the second law of thermodynamics) and oxidation is not special in this regard. And this has nothing to do with (oxidative) damage to cells. Also, the life spans of animals and plants is irrelevant here --- the question concerns the cell level.

Comment: Think of it this way:  If you took the whole sum of reactions taking place in a cell over 24 hours would
That Total
Change in Gibbs free energy be positive or negative ? It is the natural progression for ordered systems to evolve to a disordered state. Perhaps I am wrong about the oxidative stress in a mouse vs that of a plant, but you are being pedantic and not looking at the bigger picture. Entropy is the sole reason why TIME MOVES IN ONE DIRECTION and it applies to everything cells, planets, laptops, etc.

Comment: No, I think your bigger picture is wrong. The entropy law does *not* explain why cells degrade and die, because cells are not closed systems. As long as a cell has an energy source, it can maintain its state forever as far as thermodynamics is concerned. Cells die for other reasons.

Comment: the question is why are cells effected by time? Don't reduce biology to "all or nothing" level of thought, oxidation is oxidation, regardless of its Intent (metabolic oxidation does release damaging radicals regardless of its intent ) it drives the dG to become even more negative as well as other external sources etc. you may bring in glucose for example but I am talking about the sum total dG. If not entropy to explain why time moves in one direction, then what do you think is the reason cells are effected by time?